# Unable to create Windows B2s nodepool in AKS

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I need to add a Windows B2s nodepool to AKS. I am getting the folowwing error:

```
Error: Code="VMSizeIsNotPermittedToEnableAcceleratedNetworkingForVmss" Message="Virtual machine at index 0 of VM scale set /removed id of VMSS/ has size Standard_B2s, which is not compatible with enabling accelerated networking in the network profile on the scale set. Allowed sizes: Standard_D2_v4, Standard_D2s_v4, Standard_D2ds_v4, etc.
```

I am sure before this was allowed because I had created B2s and B2ms Windows nodepools before. I see it is related to accelerated networking, but how can I influence accelerated netoworking for VMSS that is yet to be created and is controlled by Azure?

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Code="VMSizeIsNotPermittedToEnableAcceleratedNetworkingForVmss"
> Message="Virtual machine at index 0 of VM scale set /removed id of
> VMSS/ has size Standard_B2s, which is not compatible with enabling
> accelerated networking in the network profile on the scale set.
> Allowed sizes: Standard_D2_v4, Standard_D2s_v4, Standard_D2ds_v4, etc

from the above error we can understand, `VMSS/ has size Standard_B2s is not NotPermitted ToEnableAcceleratedNetworking.`

**You can check the same using this Az CLI cmdlet.**
The list of Virtual Machine SKUs that support Accelerated Networking can be queried directly via the following Azure CLI [**`az vm list-skus`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-list-skus) command.

```
az vm list-skus \  
--location westus \  
--all true \  
--resource-type virtualMachines \  
--query '[].{size:size, name:name, acceleratedNetworkingEnabled: capabilities[?name==`AcceleratedNetworkingEnabled`].value | [0]}' \  
--output table
```

[image]

Would suggest you to select the node pool which is recommended one.

You can refer this [***MS Document***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/accelerated-networking-overview) for the same information.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested to add B2s in my environment with Linux nodepool and it was successful.

[image]

If your instance supports then it should be deployed with Accelerated Networking. If it does not, it should be deployed without AN. Please issue a support ticket if you can. And you can give these steps a try.

- Create nodepool with AN supported instance type.
- Scale nodepool to zero.
- Change instance type to B2s.
- Scale nodepool to one.

I shared a link below. Not the same thing but it also can give an idea.

https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1404